# DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: Django & Lambda

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, aws-lambda

I am uploading a django api to aws lambda using zappa project is built with the django3.0, postgreSQL and django rest framework. Locally everything works good but when I deploy the api to AWS Lambda I am getting the following error:

```
invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. 
You may need to add 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I have added the url as suggested by the error but when I do I get a 504 error from zappa. I have been combing stack overflow all day today and have tried many of to resolutions in other posts but none have worked for me. I have added the following to allowed hosts and still nothing

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '*******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com']
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong at this point but would really like to get this up and running. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the full project on my github

https://github.com/coffeeincodeout/membership

You can see the logs here

```
host found: [lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com]
[1579569464923] [DEBUG] 2020-01-21T01:17:44.923Z 39c648fa-bd41-4c97-86de-428c90f48197 amazonaws found in host
[1579569464924] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. You may need to add 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[1579569464924] [ERROR] 2020-01-21T01:17:44.924Z 39c648fa-bd41-4c97-86de-428c90f48197 Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. You may need to add 'lpzyjitlr0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[1579569465031] Bad Request: /dev/
[1579569465031] [WARNING] 2020-01-21T01:17:45.18Z 39c648fa-bd41-4c97-86de-428c90f48197 Bad Request: /dev/
[1579569465031] [INFO] 2020-01-21T01:17:45.19Z 39c648fa-bd41-4c97-86de-428c90f48197 66.229.9.195 - - 
[21/Jan/2020:01:17:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 65810 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36" 0/95.331
```

[image]

Comment: did you try restarting your online python server?

Comment: its serverless I am using aws lambda

Comment: your `ALLOWED_HOST` does not contain  `IpzyjitlrO.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` in https://github.com/coffeeincodeout/membership/blob/master/membership/settings.py#L28. if you want to have a wildcard to allow all host from amazonaws you can do `ALLOWED_HOST = ["*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]` [django-docs](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#setting-environment-variables). you might also wanna set this to make use of `env` variables so you don't need to commit every time you update your settings [zappa-docs](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#setting-environment-variables)

Comment: right I removed it cause every time I added it I was getting a 504 error so for some odd reason the URL is not working. I also tried using the wild card and got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue turns out I had the database connection setting to postgreSQL wrong. This is what was returning a 504 error and when adding to allowed urls it was throwing the invalid host header. Once I connected the database and ran collect static files it worked perfect.